# Is it possible to add summary statistics to a legend in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to be able to add summary statistics to a legend in print composer e.g.

GB Agricultural Land Classification:
- Grade 1 (Area: xx hectares, xx% of total)
- Grade 2 (Area: xx hectares, xx% of total)
...

The vector layer (GB Agricultural Land Classification) is styled by category (Classification - Grade 1, Grade 2 etc).

Is this possible?

Comment: Does it have to be part of the _legend_, or can it be in a text box on the layout?

Comment: I wanted it as part of the legend, it would be a good feature to be able to use an expression for legend labeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some guidelines about how to solve this:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html#data-define-the-legend-labels